# Does one say "draft email" or "email draft"?

Tags: word-order

Does one say "draft email" or "email draft"? Usage example:

https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-create-an-email-in-outlook-to-be-sent-by-someone-else ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190819030940/https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-create-an-email-in-outlook-to-be-sent-by-someone-else)):

> The recipient should download the **draft email** to his Outlook folder and finalize the communication before sending it.

https://help.bananatag.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000377103-Bananatag-Templates-VS-Drafts ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190819031301/https://help.bananatag.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000377103-Bananatag-Templates-VS-Drafts)):

> To create a new email to send out just click New **Email Draft**.

https://www.google.com/search?q="email+draft" has 62,300 results whereas https://www.google.com/search?q="draft+email" has 90,700 results so I don't see any clear signal there.

Here is the context in which I intend to use "draft email" or "email draft":

> Sounds good, please find the **draft email** below.

Answer (score 2):

Both are ok in your context.

The two words constitute a noun phrase in which the first noun modifies the second.

It might help you make a choice if you think of the first word as an adjective (although it's not) and the second as a noun.

If there is a preference, therefore, it depends on whether you want to communicate the idea that it is primarily an email (or to emphasize that it's an email, not some other kind of draft), then use *draft email*. If there's a reason to communicate that it's primarily a draft (or to emphasize that it's a draft rather than some other kind of email), then use *email draft*.

If you can't think of any reason to make one choice or the other, then use either or use *draft email* because it's usually thought of as primarily being an email. What kind? A draft email. That's why that expression is somewhat more common.